# How to create an object

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new in js. I am trying to understand how to use "this" correctly. I want to create an object with a behaviour. When the object created, the person is given a name and length of his step.

My question is how I can save the quantity of steps inside the function? how to do it correctly without losing context, because my this always looks to the global object.

Comment: How are you calling these methods?

Comment: You need "instances" of the object. You should be creating a function, rather than an object literal. Then, you can make "instances" of that object (with the `new` keyword) and `this` will bind to that particular instance.

Comment: Relevant: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) and [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: @ScottMarcus there is no need for classes or instances here (imo using "classes" in JS is an antipattern, despite ES6 giving specific syntactic support for it, although I accept that's simply an opinion which many would dispute). `person` is already an object, that would be considered an "instance" in most other languages - simply calling `person.summary()` and `person.stepIncrease()` etc should work fine, if this isn't working for the OP they should share their code.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I did not recommend classes (and I personally agree with you on that topic). However, I interpreted the question (being about `this`) as being able to keep the data from multiple uses of `Person` separate from one another. You won't get that behavior with just calling a method on an object literal because it represents a single instance. You need to be able to make separate instances of a `Person` object that are distinct.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok, but you did explicitly talk about "instances" and the `new` operator - `new` is only used either with ES6 "classes" or their pre-ES6 "fake" classes using functions. I'm happy with "factory functions" which return objects, which (imo) avoids the conclusion of JS "classes" - but those do not require the use of the `new` operator. And in any case it's not clear from the OP's question whether they need such a factory to make multiple independent "instances" or if they in fact just want to call methods on the single `person` object.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Using a `function` to create instances isn't "fake classes", nor are they "factory functions" (despite acting like them). In JS, a function used in conjunction with `new` is a first-class citizen, known as a "Constructor Function" and for `function` to be utilized as a "Constructor Function", the use of `new` is in fact required. If you don't use `new`, then you are using either an object or a method(depending on where the function is defined). (cont.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond ... This syntax and pattern is how "prototypical inheritance" and object instantiation is actually leveraged within the language. Again, the question (being about `this`) strongly implies that multiple instances need to be kept separate from each other and (if you don't use classes), then constructor functions are how that is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function that will return the person's object. Then, to create a new object, you can use the `new` keyword and call the function. This will create an object on the fly and assign the `this` pointer to the object itself.

Things to note about the `this`:

- If a function is called with .call(), .apply() or .bind(), `this` will be the object that is passed inside the call/apply/bind.
- If a function is called on an object e.g. obj.foo(), `this` will be the object it was called on.
- If a function is called on its own, `foo()`, `this` will be either undefined (strict mode) or the global object (non-strict mode)

```js
function Person(name, step=1) {
    return {
        name, 
        step,
        stepIncrease: function() {
            this.step++;
            return this;
        },
        summary: function() {
            console.log(this.step);
        }
    }

}

const john = new Person('John');
john.stepIncrease();
console.log(john);
```

Comment: There is no need for `new` here `Person("John")` will work identically to `new Person("John")` since the constructor function overrides the return value and doesn't use the `this` that `new` provides.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a function (not an arrow function) or a class. I have added a code sample of how you can create objects using function

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.step =1;
    this.stepIncrease = function() {
        this.step++;
    }
    this.summary = function () {
    return this.step;
    }
}
const person = new Person("john");
```

Answer (score 0):

with Class

```
class Person {
  name = "";
  step = 1;
  
  stepIncrease() {
    this.step++;
  }
  
  summary() {
    console.log(this.step);
  }
}

const person1 = new Person();
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  person1.stepIncrease();
}
person1.summary();
```